# How to detect modified files that were NOT checked in?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am seeing noob developers forget to check in modified files into a SVN repository. They check in only some files and leave out others!! Clearcase made it easy to see all the modified repository files. What is the equivalent command(s) in SVN which will let a noob developer see all the modified files (so all files can be checked in) ?

EDIT: Does anyone know how to do "svn  -q status" in "Tortoise Subversion" which most developers use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [relevant chapter in the SVN Manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.status), `svn status` shows you all the file and tree changes you have made.

If you have a lot of generated directories and files, that output can get a little busy, so I tend to use `svn status -q` which suppresses inclusion of ignored and non-versioned files.

It is generally good practice to do your checkins at the root of your working copy as a batch (to aggregate your changes in a single revision number).  From the root of the working copy, `svn ci` will recursively select all of the changed files for commit.  That should help avoid forgetting files.

Comment: +1 for mentioning doing commits from the working copy root. Most problems I see with developers missing files is due to commits from subdirectories or simply committing a single file. Developing a habit of both checking svn status from the root and doing commits from the root helps this immensely, as does committing all changes with one recursive commit. Also keeping developers from working on more than one "task" at a time so they can commit all changes from the root without inadvertently committing changes from another task that may not be complete yet helps as well.

Comment: Agree.  This is a training issue, not a tech issue (although there are tech helpers such as those mentioned above).  Work on this with your developers.  I think it's helpful to advocate a work cycle that becomes habit.  I usually recommend the following:

1) decide what to work on
2) open IDE
3) implement that thing
4) close IDE
5) commit from root
6) back to 1

Answer (score 2):

[`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html) let you see files that are modified or without status, like new file you forgot to put under version control

Answer (score 1):

(Responding to the Edit)

You can set Tortoise SVN to add little icon overlays to all folders/files. The red circle with an exclamation point means the file (or some file inside the folder) has uncommited changes. Right-click anywhere in a Windows Explorer window, then go to TortoiseSVN > Settings > Icon Overlays.

Personally, I don't use this much because I do most of my SVN committing/updating through Eclipse (which has similar overlays, as I imagine many other IDEs do).

Answer (score 1):

In response to how to do the equivalent of "svn status -q" in TortoiseSVN:

When you do an SVN Commit at the root of your working copy, it will bring up a window that allows you to enter a commit message. Below the message area, there is a "Changes made" list, which by default will show all version-controlled files that have been modified, as well as those files which are not under version control. If you uncheck "Show unversioned files", it will only show the modified version-controlled files, just as the -q option does for "svn status".